# Set value to post variable $this->input->post codeigniter

Tags: php, post, codeigniter-3

I know to assign a post variable as follows

```
$_POST['id'] = 5;
```

But I would like to assign post as follows

```
$this->input->post('id') = 5;
```

But it throws an error. I am using codeignter framework.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why? Any framework method would eventually have to make the assignment to `$_POST` anyway. Reading values is often more troublesome than writing which is why there is a method `input->post('key')` to read and isn't one like `input->set_post('key)` to write.

Comment: So you mean there is no option to set post manually ? @DFriend

Comment: Of course there is: `$_POST['id'] = 5;`

Comment: Other than $_POST['id'] = 5 ?

Because am in need to make use of XSS filtering

Answer (score 0):

There's a method called `set_data()` that was introduced specifically to allow validation of non-POST inputs.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post

Comment: Can you add an example to your post, if the page you link to is removed/moved then the content of this answer becomes useless.

Comment: No it does not set any value to post id.

Answer (score -4):

```
$id = $this->input->post('id');
```

Comment: Please add some context to the _code snippet_ for the benefit of the future readers.